# Nginx won't start after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, nginx

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and nginx is not starting.  One of the lines from journalctl -xe is:

```
nginx.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/nginx: No such file or directory
```

...and yes /usr/sbin/nginx doesn't exist there.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917147/nginx-wont-start-since-ubuntu-upgrade-16-04) seems the most relevant for my issue.  However given that I'm going from 16.04 to 18.04 and the problem and resolution described therein are old and were temporary I'm wondering if this is some other problem.

All help gratefully received.

Of course if the solution is as described therein then I will carry that out but I'm reluctant to do so in case I cause more harm.

---

Since posting the above I have tried to uninstall nginx using:

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common nginx-doc nginx-core nginx-full nginx-extras nginx-light
```

This gave me the message :

```
Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed
```

This is now MORE worrying because it’s not recognising nginx as installed AT ALL and yet it is there in etc/nginx and other places.

Given that nginx is such a popular and robust package I'm concerned that the upgrade managed to mess it up so much. If nothing else I think it would be worthwhile to understand what happened during the upgrade so that it can be resolved for future upgrades.

If it will help I have a Timeshift snapshot of the last 16.04 before upgrade. I can look up / check what was there if that would help.

Comment: How did you install NGINX to begin with?  It sounds like you did an installation from source and not from the packages.

Comment: @Thomas I'm sorry but the installation happened over 5 years ago and I don't have any details.  It is entirely possible that what you say is correct.  I have a vague memory that nginx wasn't in a place where I would expect it to be....and yet there are directories in etc/nginx and other places which seem normal.  If what you say is correct then what is the best way of resolving this unfortunate situation and setting it up so that it doesn't happen on the next upgrade.

Comment: The only way to solve this then is to try and manually force install the nginx packages yourself, and hope the system prioritizes those over the manually locally installed version that you have.  The other option is torch the system and install clean.  The problem with 'upgrading' is that in this case you never installed from the packages so the 'upgrade' doesn't upgrade NGINX.  And the 'unusual' place that nginx got installed *strongly* suggests you installed from source, not the packages.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks very much for your advice.  I shall attempt what you suggest but I can see further pain ahead because I have phusion passenger working in conjunction with nginx, which I suspect will fail next.  I'll update here once I've done a force install.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, not everything works always after the OS upgrade. I suggest you to reinstall and reconfigure `nginx`.

You can consult this article: [How to remove NGINX from Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-remove-nginx-from-ubuntu)

Comment: I tried to use the reinstall command for apt as per the above link but it said reinstall was an invalid operation.  I then tried: sudo apt remove nginx and it says: Package 'nginx' is not installed, so not removed.....and yet it exists in etc/nginx and MANY OTHER places as well.  Given that nginx is such a robust and common use package I'm concerned that the upgrade did something which was not intended and I believe that we need to understand what went wrong so that it can be corrected for future releases.  I sincerely hope that someone from the nginx fraternity will be able to help.

Comment: @Purvez if the package doesn't exist and `sudo apt remove nginx 'nginx-*'` doesn't work, then you did a 'from source' install and that's a lot more difficult to remove.  It may be prudent to simply start fresh with a new 18.04 install, install nginx from the repositories, and then port your application/site over manually.